# 3 Houses and Minimum cost of painting

Tags: java, algorithm

I am solving this problem

There are a row of houses, each house can be painted with three colors red, blue and green. The cost of painting each house with a certain color is different. You have to paint all the houses such that no two adjacent houses have the same color. You have to paint the houses with minimum cost. How would you do it?

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution { 
    static public int [][]v = new int[100][3];
    static public  int [][] dp = new int[100][3];

    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            v[i][0] = in.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            v[i][1] = in.nextInt() ;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            v[i][2] = in.nextInt();
        } 
        System.out.println( min_cost(n));
    }

    public static int min(int a, int b) {
        if (a <= b) {
            return a;
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static   int min(int a, int b, int c) {
        return min(min(a, b), c);
    } 

    public static int min_cost(int n) { 
        dp[1][0] = v[1][0];
        dp[1][1] = v[1][1];
        dp[1][2] = v[1][2];
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) {
            dp[i][0] = min(dp[i - 1][1], dp[i - 1][2]) + v[i][0];
            dp[i][1] = min(dp[i - 1][0], dp[i - 1][2]) + v[i][1];
            dp[i][2] = min(dp[i - 1][1], dp[i - 1][0]) + v[i][2];
        }

        int result = min(dp[n][0], dp[n][1], dp[n][2]);
        return result;
    } 
}
```

I am getting failure for half cases ...

Comment: Take a look into [Linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), and recheck your inequalities.

Comment: take look at my code i found no logical error

Comment: @T.J. Then why are you getting failure for half cases. What does that mean? And how can I determine which cases are in the failing half?

Comment: what is the value for `v`? maybe a Integer overflow?

Comment: Is there any other limitation, like using all 3 colors? Because if not then the simple solution I guess would be alternating the 2 cheaper colors. (I am guessing this wouldn't be the case though)

Comment: @Eypros the cost for each color for different houses are different. You should look at the main method. Another possible error is process the input wrongly. Normally, the input will be for each house, there will be cost for Red, green, blue. (Just my guest)

Comment: @T.J. What is the max value of `n`? If it is `100`, you have an off-by-one error : `dp` and `v` are too small.

Comment: @Pham Trung, I haven't noticed that, but as long as there is a consistency on the cheaper colors (e.g. always red, green) there should not be any change in my logic (choose the cheaper 2 that is).

Comment: I agree with @Pradhan that the off by 1 looks suspicious.  In java, generally arrays of size n start indexed by 0 and loops go while index < n.  The actual logic of the DP looks right (if using color A at index i, then find best using color B or C at index i - 1, and then add cost of color A at i).  Also, are you sure you are reading the input the right way?

Comment: Not sure how *Color A* can be both cheapest for *House 1*, and costliest for *House 2*... But interesting problem, given that the color cost sequence varies from house to house. If two colors are always cheaper than the third, houses can simply alternate between the two. If there are odd number of houses, there is only one solution - start and end with the cheapest color.

Comment: @ADTC the cost of painting each house every color is different.  Maybe the cost doesn't represent the amount of paint, but rather, the amount of owner suffering for their house to be painted a given color.

Answer (score 2):

you can use dynamic programming:

Let `F(l,c)`  be the cheapest painting of the first `l` houses, where the last house is colored `c`
Let `w(k,c)` be the cost of painting the `k`-th house as `c`

then

`F(0,c) = 0` for all `c in colors`

recursive `F`:

`F(k,c) = min( F(k-1,cc) + w(k,c) : cc in colors and cc!=c )`

answer:

`min( F(l,cc) : cc in colors)`

Comment: I think his solution is similar to this :) , look at his last `min_cost` method, he implemented a bottom up dp.